# regex ok but does not works

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

This code does not works, why?

```
std::cmatch result;
std::string str("trucmuch.service\n   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)\n   Active: inactive (dead)... (101)");
std::regex rgx("Loaded:\s+(\S+)(?:\s+\((?:Reason:\s*)?([^)]*)\))?", std::regex::ECMAScript);
std::regex_match(str.c_str(), result, rgx);
qDebug() << result.size();
```

Display 0 !!

How I can get result[0] and result[1](https://regex101.com/r/tY0eA8/1) ("not-found", "No such file or directory")?

Test on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tY0eA8/1)

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match). `std::regex_match` matches the entire string; you probably want `std::regex_search`. And while you're at it, why don't you use `std::smatch` instead of `std::cmatch`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `std::regex_search` to find substrings that match your pattern. You also need to escape the backslashes properly, or even better, use raw string literals. The following works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::smatch result;

    std::string str =
        "trucmuch.service\n   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file "
        "or directory)\n   Active: inactive (dead)... (101)";

    std::regex rgx(R"(Loaded:\s+(\S+)(?:\s+\((?:Reason:\s*)?([^)]*)\))?)",
                   std::regex::ECMAScript);

    std::regex_search(str, result, rgx);

    for (const auto & sm : result) { std::cout << sm << '\n'; }
}
```